# Get only image url from phpbb post text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, phpbb

Since PHPBB have its own way of calling the inline images, i have post_text something like this

```
test content [img:32acu135]http&#58;//mywebsite&#46;com&#46;pk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/some-thing-3&#46;jpg[/img:32acu135]
```

in database,
is there any way that i can call the first image in the content, may be using preg_match_all or regex..

Comment: What's your expted output?

Comment: the image url http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/something-3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a regex like

```
\[img.+?\](.*)\[\/img.+?\]
```

and take  the capturing group

php example

```
$re = "/\\[img.+?\\](.*)\\[\\/img.+?\\]/"; 
$str = "[img:32acu135]http&#58;//mywebsite&#46;com&#46;pk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/some-thing-3&#46;jpg[/img:32acu135]"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print($matches[1]);
```

Result :

> http://mywebsite.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/some-thing-3.jpg